# How to replace NA in a vector using `[` as a function?

Tags: r

I recently learned that `` `[` `` can be used as a function to index vectors/data frames. I was experimenting with it on my own and have a short question.

I have the following vector and want to replace the NA using `` `[` `` function. My intention was to replace the NA with a string e, but it did not work. `x` became a vector with single element `e` instead. Could you help me understand how `` `[` `` works as a function call? Thank you

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", NA, "f", "g")

x <- x %>% `[`(is.na(.)) %>% `<-`("e")
> x
[1] "e"

# above code isn't equivalent to this? 
x[is.na(x)] <- "e"

> x
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want, but you can replace NA values in a vector with the `replace_na` function from the tidyverse. Just be sure to run `library(tidyverse)` and then you can do `x %>% replace_na("e")`. It doesn't use the `[` operator though, so I'm not sure it actually meets your requirements.

Comment: Functions that can be on the left side of an assignment normally have a special version: ``x %>% `[<-`(is.na(.), "e")``

Comment: Expanding on Ricardo's comment, as you say in the question, `[` is a function for indexing. `\`[<-\`()` is a function for replacing items in an index.

Comment: @Ricardo Semião e Castro Thank you for your help! in my original code I have more functions in the pipes and ``  `[<-`  ``  does exactly what I needed. I was looking at the documentation and found that ```?InternalMethods``` lists different versions of similar functions. thanks again